# Using WCF to execute code & return objects in another CLR address space

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, proxy, remoting

After some reading, i've gather .NET Remoting is a deprecated API which has been replaced by WCF.

I'm writing an automation framework, and would like to reference a DLL with types/methods either locally, or on some remote machine, and execute them without respect to where they are executing.

I thought Remoting is the way to go, since i guess all functionality is performed on a proxy object, making it irrelevant if it is a local object or remote.

How can WCF perform this kind of action (if at all) or .NET Remoting is the way to go ?

Or perhaps some other option i haven't thought of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no magic way to call a method completely transparent without regards to which machine to run it on, as far as I know, including .NET Remoting.
However, WCF makes extensive use of proxies, either generated automatically from WSDL documents or by directly referencing the types/interfaces from a shared dll.

Thus, you could create a shared dll containing some methods, add some WCF plumbing (i.e. creating a Service interface out of the methods/types you want to expose) and then decide whether to use them directly/locally in your project, or access them via a proxy. This makes it fairly easy to invoke methods remotely. Note however that you cannot create fully-fledged classes that expose state and functionality remotely, the memory holding the actual objects are not shared remotely, it is, after all, just a 'trick'.

Depending on your setup, you may:

- Use **Named Pipes** for intra-machine communication (fastest)
- Use **TCP** for Intranet communication (also pretty fast)
- Use **HTTP/HTTPS** for Internet communication (slowest)

Although it is easy to invoke remote methods, including sending/returning complex data structures, WCF internally creates a full communication stack, possibly consisting of lots of logic, including for example security, transaction and reliability. This means that remote communication comes with a cost, both stressing the CPU and the network.

A primer to WCF can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee958158.aspx).

If you want more performance than possible with the built in communication options, you may want to consider using something like [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) to both slim down the amount of data being transferred and to lower the CPU load.

For C# there are two implementations of Protocol Buffers that I know of, [Protobuf CSharp](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) by Jon Skeet and [Protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) by Marc Gravell.

A final note just to be clear; no, WCF **does not** give you a way to fully abstract away the location of types/methods.

Comment: I meant that abstracting away remote/local execution will be reduced to minimum effort. I suppose that i could share a library (DLL) with methods/types to be executed, having some logic selecting where to execute at runtime. Is this the way it could work ?

Comment: Well, yes, more or less, given that you treat the methods/types as stateless services. For example, 'local.GetCustomers()' vs 'proxy.GetCustomers()' or 'local.CreateCustomer(name)' vs 'proxy.CreateCustomer(name)'. If the logic is not stateless, switching between local/proxy objects at runtime will **not** work since the state is **not** shared between the local/proxy objects.

Comment: Btw, it seems a bit odd switching between local/remote during runtime, what are you trying to build?

Comment: We are building an in-house automation tool. This tool offers a .NET API for developing "actions" such as "press key on GUI" or "read registry" or basically what not. The model used is 1 central location where the tool is run, being able to "send commands" to other servers. I'd like to architect it in such a way in which it would be transparent to the controlling machine, whether the action is being executed locally or remotely. I plan to have some service sitting on remote machines waiting for commands (either by WCF or whatever).

Comment: Ah, ok. You do not need to have different code paths for remote/local as you can use WCF to communicate on the same machine as well. Of course it would be a lot more _efficient_ to reference the "server" dll directly, but in your case performance seems to be less of a concern. Having a simple architecture is probably more important. So, use WCF in both situations, it is just a matter of configuring it the way you want it. (unless I missed the point completely). Cheers.

Comment: yes i agree with u - simplicity is a must and i think that the performance penalty would not matter; what we'd gain is the seamless ability to run different steps on different machines, without making things more complex than they already are.

Answer (score 2):

.NET Remoting is indeed pretty much deprecated.

WCF has proxy objects just like .NET remoting...whereas in .NET remoting the proxy objects are MarshalByRef objects, in WCF the proxy objects are interfaces or classes attributed with the ServiceContract attribute.

There is no real magic in .NET remoting...it just seems more like magic because a lot less of the plumbing is exposed and pluggible. Even in WCF, at the root of all the infrastructure, the framework creates a RealProxy...the same type used by .NET Remoting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.aspx.

At the end of the day, pretty much anything you would previously have used .NET Remoting for can be done with WCF. The only thing I know of that truly functions intrinsically differently is the notions of asynchronous callbacks (which, IMHO didn't work so well in .NET Remoting anyway).

Answer (score 1):

WCF uses a SOA approach:

You can define ServiceContracts and DataContracts,
however, you can not expose objects with both state and functionality.

The ServiceContract is an object who's lifetime is not connected to that of the DataContracts,
it can be either a singleton, or created at each call.

The DataContracts are just dumb data, sent back a forth between server and client.
Only their DataMembers are exposed to the client.

The ServiceContracts expose all the methods to your client as OperationContracts that can receive and return DataContracts.

WCF creates proxies for ServiceContract and DataContracts on the client side, so you don't need to think about sending/receiving packages and such when you write a service or consume it.

Whatever approach you take, there are considerations you must think of regarding whether the code is ran in the same application or via another application (locally or remotely) - thread safety, synchronization, events, time outs, and more.